# jQuery functions work in console, but not live

Tags: jquery, child-theme, scripts

I am trying to traverse the DOM in a number of places, replacing some of the content.

```
jQuery('.homepage_buttons_text a[href^="http://danrobertsgroup.com/?attachment_id=1037"]').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).html("<h1 class='homepage_button_title'>Workouts</h1><span class='homepage_button_title'>Books / DVD's / Downloads</span>");
});
```

this works fine when doing it in the console, but isn't working when I put it in the scripts file.

I am running a child-theme and enqueuing properly I think:

```
function child_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'child-scripts',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/child-scripts.js',
     array( 'jquery' ),
    '1.0',
    true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

It all loads fine. I have even called child-scripts.js in the footer and in very last place - but still no joy.

It's pretty annoying, any help appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest using [jQuery(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using the jQuery code we see in question? If you are using it in header (head), I would recommend using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.homepage_buttons_text a[href^="http://danrobertsgroup.com/?attachment_id=1037"]').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).html("<h1 class='homepage_button_title'>Workouts</h1><span class='homepage_button_title'>Books / DVD's / Downloads</span>");
    });
});
```

If you are using the code in the footer, the above replacement is still recommended and for each `add_action` hook you can use the priority parameter:

```
function child_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'child-scripts',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/child-scripts.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '1.0',
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_enqueue_scripts', 30 );
```